# sqlplus connect but sql developer and jdeveloper does not

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper, jdeveloper

today suddenly SQL developer stop connecting to oracle database and jdeveloper either.
it gives me the infamous error message **IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**

BUT when i connect throw SQL plus, it connects normally.
i disabled firewall but still get the error.
yesterday i made restore point for my windows Operating system. i don't know if this has anything to do with the problem. but this is the only thing i remember I did.

i was working normally for weeks and this happened now. 
how can I solve the problem? I need to wokr on JDeveloper and SQL developer

**OracleDBConsoleorcl** service does not start, is this what caused the problem? and how to start it

after restaring the pc even sqlPlus does not connect and tells me that oracle doesnot exist

Comment: I made restart to pc the error in sql developer changed to the follwoing   Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: Delete your listener and create it again it solve the problem

Comment: well after restart even sql plus gives me this: ora-01034:oracle does not exist and also this error: ora-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to start->programs-> {oracle database instance }-> configuration and migration tools -> **Net Configuration Assistant**

a window will open, select the first option( listener configuration) click next and select delete and finish.

Then again select listener configuration and then select add and finish

I don't remember exactly how I solved the problem. In my notes I had scribbled something below. You can try

**Resolving problem with TNS server.**

1. Delete the listener first and create new listener  from  Net
   configuration assistant in start menu
2. If doesn’t resolve, Check if TNS service(oracleTNSListner) is running
   If service is not running, try to start other oracle DB services and at last try to start TNS ser vice.
3. If TNS service starts and stops. Set the Environment ORCALE_HOME variable to oracle installation folder[ c:\app\user\oracle\product\version..\bin]
4. Check if TNS service is  pointing to $oracle_home\bin\TNSLRN service of the current SID,
   If not goto registry ->  local_machine -> currentcontrolset -> services -> service name-> change the path.
5. Start the service.
6. How to check if the service is running or not
   Got to net manager->service manager, select SID and click test connection. 
   Command line:
   Lsnrctl[enter]
   Lsnrctl>status   [gets u the status of the listener]
   Lsnrctl>start [LISTENER NAME]

Comment: i did but nothing changed, i think there is something with oracle service, how can i check that?

Comment: go to windows services (services.msc) there would a srvice by name oracle{your sid} check if its started

Comment: Thank your first line fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your sql developer roaming profile in

```
C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer
```

Note that this action will delete all of your connections therefore backup your connections first. After that try to connect again.